# Cloud Firestore billing for write functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Please tell me how much more does it cost to write documents within sub-collections as compared to documents in (main) collections in cloud firestore. I know the query adds one extra step. I am considering using this method for my group chat web app.

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't  matter where your write whether it's a sub-collection or main collection firebase will charge same.